# Modify Woocommerce Flickity Slider from Horizontal to Vertical Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm hoping that someone might be able to help me with this issue. I'm working within a premade Wordpress theme called Flatsome. It uses the Foundations framework.

Within the default configuration the Woocommerce thumbnails appear in the standard location which is beneath the main product image. I would like to move the thumbnails from below the product image to the left of the product image.

The theme is using the Flickity slider so in order to do this I need to modify the layout of the theme, which I can do myself, but also modify the slider so that it's a vertical slider rather than a horizontal slider.

To see a real life example of this please visit

http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/product/wicked-ss-o-neck-selected-homme/

The above site is the exact same code as the site that I'm working upon. Below is the code that is used for the product thumbnails.

```
<ul class="product-thumbnails  thumbnails js-flickity slider-nav-small"
    data-flickity-options='{ 
            "cellAlign": "left",
            "wrapAround": false,
            "autoPlay": false,
            "prevNextButtons":true,
            "asNavFor": ".product-gallery-slider",
            "percentPosition": true,
            "imagesLoaded": true,
            "pageDots": false,
            "selectedAttraction" : 0.1,
            "friction": 0.6,
            "rightToLeft": false,
            "contain": true
        }'
    >           
    <li class="is-nav-selected first"><a href="">
        <img width="114" height="130" src="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-Top-Main-Custom-114x130.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Angel-Top-Main (Custom)" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  href="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-Top-Main-Custom.jpg" class="zoom" title="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="114" height="130" src="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-Top-Main-Custom-114x130.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="Angel-Top-Main (Custom)" title="Angel-Top-Main (Custom)" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  href="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-Tops1.jpg" class="zoom" title="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="114" height="130" src="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-Tops1-114x130.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="Angel-Tops1" title="Angel-Tops1" /></a></li>
    <li>
        <a  href="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-Tops2.jpg" class="zoom" title="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="114" height="130" src="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-Tops2-114x130.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="Angel-Tops2" title="Angel-Tops2" /></a></li>
    <li>
        <a  href="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ANGEL-TOP3.1-1.jpg" class="zoom" title="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="114" height="130" src="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ANGEL-TOP3.1-1-114x130.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="ANGEL-TOP3.1" title="ANGEL-TOP3.1" /></a></li>
    <li>
        <a  href="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-top4.1.jpg" class="zoom" title="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"><img width="114" height="130" src="http://gypsyofeden.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Angel-top4.1-114x130.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail size-shop_thumbnail" alt="Angel-top4.1" title="Angel-top4.1" /></a></li></ul>
```

I found the following example on Codepen which looks like it's exactly what I want yet it's above my skill level to be able to implement it within my current website.

https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/dMjbjR

Does anybody know how I might be able to achieve these? To be honest if someone can assist me with the css / flickity settings to modify the slider into a vertical slider then I can do the rest with the positioning and layout.

Thanks so much

Byron